# TomEE pluME with JSF 2.2 ConfigurationException

Tags: java, jsf, tomcat, jsf-2.2, tomee-7

When I start tomEE to deploy my project. I get errors.

I am using JSF 2.2, apache-tomee-7.0.0-M3-plume, and Primefaces latest version.

I searched but I didn't find any solution.

**TomEE Errors**

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: **Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.**
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:330)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:439)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4812)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5255)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.faces.FacesException: com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:407)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:251)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:543)
    at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
    at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.webbeans.jsf.OwbApplicationFactory.getApplication(OwbApplicationFactory.java:43)
    at com.sun.faces.application.InjectionApplicationFactory.getApplication(InjectionApplicationFactory.java:93)
    at com.sun.faces.config.InitFacesContext.getApplication(InitFacesContext.java:142)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

**Web.xml**

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <web-app
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
   http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" id="WebApp_ID"
   version="3.1">   <display-name>FileUpload</display-name>  
   <welcome-file-list>
       <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>   </welcome-file-list>   <context-param>
       <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
       <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
       <param-value>client</param-value>   </context-param>   <context-param>
       <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
       <param-value>resources.application</param-value>   </context-param>   <filter>
       <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class>
   </filter>   <filter-mapping>
       <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>   </filter-mapping>   <servlet>
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
       <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>   </servlet>   <servlet-mapping>
       <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
       <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>   </servlet-mapping>   <listener>
       <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
   </listener> </web-app>
```

Comment: Just because this is your first post, there is no reason you can't create a good question. Be sure to read over [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and follow all of the tips and suggestions, and you should be able to make a good question.